# Django MPTT maximum elements in recursetree

Tags: django, django-templates, django-mptt, mptt

Is there a way to present a partial tree using Django-MPTT's `{% recursetree %}` **without retrieving the entire tree** from database? I need to show the first 20 nodes encountered by a Depth First Search.

Either of these (which do not retrieve the full tree) cause an exception:

```
# resulting querySet passed to {% recursetree %} in template
Thing.objects.all()[:20]

# directly sliced in template
{% recursetree all_nodes|slice:":20" %}
```

`AssertionError while rendering: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken`.

This on the other hand does work, but retrieves the entire tree:

```
 # resulting querySet passed to {% recursetree %} in template
 list(Thing.objects.all())[:20]
```

How can I do this without retrieving the entire tree form the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPTT uses pre-order (which is a depth-first search already.) So all you need to do is add a limit to your queryset before passing it to recursetree.

MPTT calls `order_by()` if you pass a queryset to `recursetree`, but it can't do that if you pass a list. That behaviour is kind of confusing and has caused other people issues too.

I've created a [ticket on MPTT](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/281) to address this.

In the meantime, you can just do the slicing before the list() call:

```
list(Thing.objects.all()[:20])
```

That will do the limit in the database, then convert the queryset to a list, which you can pass to `recursetree` without it trying to reorder things.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives an exception in `{% recursetree %}`. See my updated question.

Comment: So it does. Edited to fix that.